# wpf MVVM ObservableCollection<string> does not update view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I am having an issue where my ObservableCollection is not updating the view.  I can place a breakpoint prior to the OnPropertyChange and can verify that my collection has the names in them.

In my model i have a event that fires a List with random names in it.

in my view model i subscribe to this event and my event handler does this

```
void _manager_ProcessesChanged(List<string> n)
    {
        //create a new collection to hold current Ids
        ObservableCollection<string> names = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        //copy ids into our collection
        foreach (string name in n)
        {
            names.Add(name);
        }

        Names = names;
    }
```

my Names property looks like so

```
ObservableCollection<string> _names = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Names
    {
        get { return _names; }
        set
        {
            _names = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Names");
        }
    }
```

and my view binds looks like this

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}"/>
</Grid>
```

If i change the collection for `<string>` to `<int>` it seems to work fine.. what am i missing?

Comment: FYI, `_manager_ProcessesChanged` can be simplified to one line: `Names = new ObservableCollection<string>(n);`

Comment: The reason i am doing this like this is because the event is firing from another thread.  This is the only way i could figure out how to get around the cross threading issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this as well. Not sure if this is the ideal solution (sure doesn't seem like it) but this has worked for me

```
void _manager_ProcessesChanged(List<string> n)
{
    Names.Clear();

    //copy ids into our collection
    foreach (string name in n)
    {
        Names.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how you should do it since ObservableCollection will already notify the UI without having to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the collection.

Comment: same result, Listbox is empty

Answer (score 5):

If you re-instantiate the ObservableCollection you will lose your binding to the collection.

You should .Clear(...) and .Add(...) the items, and you should also just change ObservableCollection Names to an auto-property.  No need to call OnPropertyChanged here, as it is handled by the type for you.

Comment: Is there really no way to re-instantiate and keep the binding?

Comment: @FrancoisBotha One way is to add RaisePropertyChanged method to your ObservableCollection setter. Then the UI will update after re-instantiating. It works but I don't know why. ObservableCollection should have a built-in INPC implementation accroding to microsoft documentation.